# Empty space at the bottom of the html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, backbone.js

I have run into an issue with white space outside of the html document on the window. I have a live version [here](http://peterbenavides.site/backbone_scraper/scraper.html) illustrating the problem. There is a large amount of whitespace at the bottom of the page, which appears to be outside of the bound of the html document itself. I have a feeling this is caused by this CSS:

```
#content {
width: 80%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: 640px;
overflow-y: scroll;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I am using backbone to query a Flickr API to get the data and then display them as items in the index view. However, I think this is changing the height of the document, and I can't seem to be able to make it smaller (the window and document heights seem to be fine afterwards, but there is a huge whitespace after the scrolling div which is not in the html doc).

**EDIT:**
So the issue is caused by text that I have set to "visibility: none". I have set this instead to "display: none", and it fixed the issue. I had "visibility: none" because I thought I would not be able to access the pixel width using jQuery, but I was apparently mistaken.

Comment: Adding the `position:relative` seems to work.

Comment: [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/33vupLb2/) of how setting `position:relative` on the container makes absolutely positioned children respect the overflow (as opposed to [no positioning](http://jsfiddle.net/33vupLb2/1/)).

Comment: Thanks for the help, this also works! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `.container` in the `body` or a `div` with `position: fixed` around your `#content`. The hidden list elements are rendered and pushing the parent containers to the bottom.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up switching the elements to "display: none" instead. I was using visibility to test for pixel width, but the feature I was using that for is working fine with "display: none".  I will mark this as the answer though, because this is another way to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the height of `#content` to `height: 100%`. Of course, relative sizing can be problematic for embedded or external DOM elements, but as I experimented with your page, it is to me ok.

**Extension:** That minor effect is caused by the `overflow: auto` css setting. The browser doesn't know that the content of the div `#content` won't overflow horizontally, and thus it lets place to its vertical scrollbar. In some browsers, there are different `overflow-x:` and `overflow-y:` settings for that, but it is not standard (even in them doesn't work correctly). There are more details in my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808413/css3-box-sizing-margin-box-why-not/20189812#20189812) answer.

There is no simple and browser-independent solution for this problem.

Comment: The effect is not obvious if you just scroll in the div#content. Scrolling outside of that quickly reveals a huge amount of empty space after the div#content.  Setting the height to 100% does not achieve the effect I'm looking for. I am trying to get the div#content to be a fixed height which can then scroll through the index items.

Comment: @PeterBenavides Ok, I understand now. I extended my answer, what about now?

Comment: I'm not sure that the overflow directions were causing it. I am pretty sure the extra space was caused by divs with "visibility: hidden"

Comment: @PeterBenavides Then set an "overflow: hidden" for the `#content` and you will be surprised. `visibility: hidden` divs are non-entities in the layout since around ie6.

Answer (score -1):

set height to height:auto;
the height is hardcoded

Comment: The height is hard coded because I would like the scrolling div to be a set height, so that you can scroll through the items without scrolling through the rest of the page. Setting the height to auto does not fix the problem.